# What is to Reign on David's throne?

Tags: jesus, isaiah, david

What does it mean to Reign on David's throne in this verse?

```
For to us a child is born,
    to us a son is given,
    and the government will be on his shoulders.
And he will be called
    Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God,
    Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.
7 Of the greatness of his government and peace
    there will be no end.
He will reign on David’s throne
    and over his kingdom,
establishing and upholding it
    with justice and righteousness
    from that time on and forever.
The zeal of the Lord Almighty
    will accomplish this.
```

Comment: To be king of Israel.

Comment: Does it have any relation with David? Does that mean that whoever comes must do things like David did?

Comment: It certainly does. It's a reference to God's promise to David regarding his seed (cp. Psa. 132:11). As for doing things like David, I'm not sure.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I guess that verse in Psalm answers it... a descendant from David.

Comment: @User be sure to give a reference for verses in the future also - this is well known so it's pretty easy, but specific references will help others find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is to Reign on David's throne in Isaiah 9:7?

Possibly Isaiah was contemplating the promise to David about the longevity of the kingdom which God promised would come through the line of David (2 Samuel 7:16). The Messiah, is to be a descendant of David, and will fulfill this prophetic promise.

One of the titles of the Messiah is the Prince of Peace (indicating rulership). Messiah is the One who will usher in and maintain the thousand years of. It is the Messiah who is seated on David’s throne (Luke 1:32–33), and he will have an eternal rule of peace and justice. His rule will have no end; it will go on forever (cf. Daniel 7:14, 27; Micah 4:7; Luke 1:33; Revelation 11:15).

Just as David was king over Israel, Messiah is going to be King ***over all creation.***

Comment: "Answers should show sensitivity to other users of the site. This may include an extra explanation when later texts are applied to earlier texts (e.g. ones that read Jesus into the Hebrew Bible). Claims that could reasonably be seen as controversial or offensive must be relevant and supported from the text. "Supported" means an explicit link or citation of text, or clear logical reasoning starting from a cited text" (from [guidelines on showing your work](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/777/423)).

Comment: You could even just say something like, "From a Christian perspective" and that is sufficient - but somehow justify your leap from Isaiah to these other texts written in other time periods by different authors. [You may find this helpful as you think through this.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/771/423) Christians are used to bringing lots of assumptions to the table that we expect some work to be shown for here as we don't Christian (or any religious) theology as a given.

Comment: I do not think this is the right place for me. I am not getting it.

Comment: [Have you read this post about how we're a little different from other sites that study the Bible?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) You may find it helpful.

Comment: @DrFry: Ah :(. Don't worry about it brother. Your answer was perfectly fine, to me. I guess when you mention the "NT" here on BH.SE, then heads spin. Whatever. I upvoted you anyway.

Comment: I think your answer is fine also +1. & I think you are catching on. I'm pretty sure Dan is expressing personal preferences here, not site policy. Perhaps he downvoted and is just communicating his reason for his downvote.  It is true that the site is diverse/not Christian; however, how that is handled has been a matter of considerable discussion.  Bottom line is this: the NT is an agreed upon text for the forum. Thus, if a matter is asserted in the NT, cite the reference and don't feel you have to reestablish it as fact through showing the steps. If it is not stated out right, show your steps.

Comment: DrFry I think you are getting it well enough: I appreciate your answers here including this one, so please don't get discouraged and give up on us :)

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 perhaps you should consider [voting on meta](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/920/43) more? Your voice there has equal standing with everyone else's.